# Offset appearing between particles and mesh

Tags: particles

I checked the scaling,vertex paint,origin etc everything seems fine but there is huge offset between the particles and the mesh when i render particles as a whole collection. Can anyone please help me solve the problem...im just a newbie to blender.

[image: Vertex group]

[image: Particle settings]

[image: Particles problem]

Comment: I have used the same vertex group for the particles system(branches)

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=BndG2WzN" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/BndG2WzN/)

Comment: you can share it here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ just follow the instructions

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=BndG2WzN" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/BndG2WzN/)

Comment: could you please upload a version which actually shows your problem. In your file...there are no active particles at all, so i assume...maybe...you renamed your collection leaves to archive or...!?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=YwNQxqAQ" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/YwNQxqAQ/)

Comment: Sorry i had removed the particles as my pc was lagging because of it

Comment: you cannot have an object with particle system as rendered object of a particle system -> looks like Blender cannot do this.

Comment: No I applied the particle system of the leaves on twigs,ctrl-j'd the leaves,then parented the twigs.

Comment: So there's no particle system on the twigs